# ARM Template for FileShare on Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template

I've created a storage account with Azure Functions etc.
The setup is fairly simple - and i've now exported it to an ARM template.

To test it, i've removed the resources from Azure, and tried to use the template to create things.

However, i have this section to create the required File shares:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
    "apiVersion": "2021-08-01",
    "name": "funcstoretest/default/scale-test1546",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices', 'funcstoretest', 'default')]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 'funcstoretest')]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "accessTier": "TransactionOptimized",
        "shareQuota": 5120,
        "enabledProtocols": "SMB"
    }
},
```

Actually using this exported sample always results in the following error however:

> There were errors in your deployment.
>
> Error code: DeploymentFailed.
>
> ##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
>
> ##[error]Details:
>
> ##[error]InvalidHeaderValue: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.

Now, removing the section that defines the properties (i.e. accessTier, shareQuota, enabledProtocols) allows the deploy to continue, but results in an unusable share with Azure Functions complaining it can't find the runtime (and with no functions being deployed when i do a deploy).

Any ideas on how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. it works perfectly.

***Make sure passing required appsetting, as function app will try to connect to the storage account, if its not added, it will be facing Runtime unreachable error.***

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "appName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat('fnapp', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the function app that you wish to create."
      }
    },
    "storageAccountType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Storage Account type"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    },
    "runtime": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "node",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The language worker runtime to load in the function app."
      }
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string"
      }
    
  },
  "variables": {
    "functionAppName": "[parameters('appName')]",
    "hostingPlanName": "[parameters('appName')]",
    "functionWorkerRuntime": "[parameters('runtime')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "Storage",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Y1",
        "tier": "Dynamic"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
        "computeMode": "Dynamic"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('storageAccountName'), ';EndpointSuffix=', environment().suffixes.storage, ';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('storageAccountName'), ';EndpointSuffix=', environment().suffixes.storage, ';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
              "value": "[toLower(variables('functionAppName'))]"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~2"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
              "value": "~10"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
              "value": "[variables('functionWorkerRuntime')]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
   
  ]
}
```

Pass the follwoing parameters to it

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "appName": {
      "metadata": {
        "description": "This Param will set the FA name & hostingPlanName"

      },
      "value": "yourappservicename_FunctionappName"
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "metadata": {
        "descrption": "Name of the storage account that will be conected & configured with teh function app"
      },
      "value": "Storage_Account_name"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question. OP is running into issues with creating File Share with properties using an ARM template and your solution is creating a Function app and a storage account.

Comment: File share exist in a storage account. First you have to create it then create the function & pass the connection string of the storage account. Creation of fileshare is not required explicitly. Function app will create it. Try above template. Here appsetting do that connection between azure function & storage.

Comment: This worked fine - the real issue i had was that i was configuring the File share directly, when letting the functions app do it was the correct way.
I took the app settings section from the SiteConfig section, and added that to my templare. Then, removed the FileShare definition.
Good call Iokaneth!

Comment: It is interesting however, that i can export an entire resource group to ARM Template - but that template will not work to recreate the resources. Very annoying.

Comment: Yes, those are for template purpose but might not work everytime . need to create a seperate ARM project.

Comment: for me, the deployment was failing with invalid header error and turns out the file share name i was passing was not in the right format. It cannot have special characters, numbers, capital letters and spaces. After i fixed that, the deployment worked. The error is misleading given what really was wrong. So in your case, you should remove all that from the name "scale-test1546". 
ps: i know im a year late :p